# SSIS Inserts not inserting the computed columns

Tags: ssis, bulkinsert, calculated-columns

I am using SSIS to insert a Excel file into a Sql Server Table. I believe it uses the Bulk insert, and as a result it doesn't insert into the 'CreationDate' and the 'ModificationDate' columns (both of which are computed columns with getdate() as the default).

Is there a way to get around this problem?

Also, just to be clear - both these date columns are not a part of excel. Here is the exact scenario:

My excel has two columns - code and description. My SQL Server table has 4 columns Code, Description, CreationDate, ModificationDate.

So, when the SSIS copies the data, it copies Code and Description, but the CreationDate and ModificationDate (which are SQL Server Computed Columns) are both empty.

Comment: By computed do you mean "computed column in SSIS" or "normal columns in the target table with defaults"? "Computed column" has a precise meaning in SQL Server and this doesn't sound like it

Comment: It's "Computed Columns" in SQL Server. It's computed using the sqlserver command getdate()

Comment: @Prabhuram - it's not. If you *had* a computed column defined as `CreationDate as getdate()`, it would always return the current datetime. What you mean, as gbn hinted, is that the columns have a default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a normal column with a *default constraint* if you want to log creation
A [*computed column*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) defined as `GETDATE()` will change every time you query it.

It is also impossible for a computed column to *not* be populated

So, assuming you mean "normal column with default", then you need [stop sending NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx) from SSIS which overrides the default

This is all demonstrated here:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (
   bar int NOT NULL,
   testCol1Null datetime NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
   testCol1NotNull datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
   testCol2 AS GETDATE()
   );
INSERT #foo (bar, testCol1Null) VALUES (1, NULL);

SELECT * FROM #foo;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.100';
SELECT * FROM #foo;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.100';
SELECT * FROM #foo;

DROP TABLE #foo;
```

Assuming you are using the [Bulk Insert Task in SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188471.aspx), then you need to set "Keep nulls = off/unchecked" in the options page

Answer (score 1):

You should have a default constraint on the column(s) that specifies get

```
col1 datetime default getdate()
```

There should also be an option for the bulk insert `KEEPNULLS` which should be turned off.

From [Bulk Insert on MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

> Specifies that empty columns should retain a null value during the bulk-import operation, instead of having any default values for the
>   columns inserted. For more information, see Keeping Nulls or Using
>   Default Values During Bulk Import.

KEEPNULLS is also documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Put in a Derived Column in your dataflow and populate the two missing columns with the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

The value on a computed column doesn't physically exists on the database, it is calculated every time SQL Server needs to access it,  that's why you can't inform a value to it on a insert.

What you need is a default column, which is a column that has a default value that's inserted if you don't inform any other value.

```
CreationDate datetime default getdate()
ModificationDate datetime default getdate()
```